# VBA Shows Listbox is Always Null Even When Option Is Selected

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, ms-access-2013

I created a listbox and added it to my user form from the GUI.  The list box is single select and is one column.  3 options were added via the Row Source; the values are "", "jimmy", "jack" and I have the following vba to ensure an option was selected

```
If IsNull(Me!List10) Then
    MsgBox "Please Select A Value!", vbOKOnly
    Me.List10.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
Else
    selectedoption = Me!List10
End If
```

Now the issue I have is even when a value is selected the MsgBox still displays informing the user to select a value, so there is no way to pass!  What would be the proper syntax to check if a listbox is null?

**EDIT**
This syntax will work if the user clicks the button on the user form while the list box is still selected (has focus), but it seems that the syntax can not retain the value if the list box does not have focus...

Comment: What is the value of the listbox's Bound Column property?  It must be 1 else the listbox will always return null.

Comment: @mdialogo - it is set to 1.  The listbox will return the appropriate value if it has focus when the button is pressed, if the listbox does not have focus then it returns null.

Comment: There's something else going on. As soon as you click the button, the listbox loses focus, so i don't think focus is the issue. edit, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice the first time that the first entry on your value list is "".

One "fix" (hack) would be to add a space " ".

The problem must be happening only when that first entry is selected. Does it need to be there?